# 配列から特定式で表したインデックスの要素だけを抜き出す方法

Tags: ruby

例えばインデックス表す式を`3n-2`としたときに、その式に適合するインデックスの要素だけを配列から抜き出したいといった場合があります。

```
(概念的にはこんな感じ)
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]  => [b,e] ※ 1 <= n <= 2 のとき
```

最初は以下のようなものを考えてみたのですが、これだと`n`の範囲をあらかじめ分かっていないと使えません。

```
a = [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e, :f, :g]
b = []
1.upto(2){|n| b << a[n * 3 - 2]}
#=> 1
b.compact
#=> [:b, :e]
```

泥臭いやり方でも、スマートなやり方でも、どちらでも良いので、`n`の範囲をあらかじめ考えずともできる方法を探しているのですが思いつきません。
[言語リファレンス](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/library/_builtin.html)を見ながら考えてはみたのですが、試しているうちに混乱してしまいました。
初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、どなたか良い解法がありましたら教えてください。

Comment: `n`の範囲をあらかじめ考えなくても求めたいことを書き漏れていたので追記しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@BLUEPIXY さんとほぼ同案ですが、`.with_index` を使ってもう少しシンプルに。

```
b = a.select.with_index { |x, i| i%3 == 1 }
# => [:b, :e]
```

Comment: BLUEPIXYさん、Seieiさんの内容でも実行結果でできているのは分かっていたのですが、私の頭がついていけてませんでした。要するに3で割って余りが1のインデックスのものだけ集めれば良い、ということなので、結果的にはですがyasuさんのが一番直観的に分かりやすかったのでこれで解決とさせていただきました。

Answer (score 2):

方法は色々有ると思います、一例として

```
a = [*'a'..'g'].each_with_index.select{ |e,i| i % 3 == 1}.map{|e| e[0]}
p a #["b", "f"]
```

説明：
`each_with_index` で要素とインデックスを得られるので、
それから条件で`select`して
`map`で要素だけに戻す処理です。

Answer (score 2):

```
  a = [:a,:b,:c,:d,:e,:f,:g]
  n_range = 1..2
  a.select.with_index {|_v, index|
    n_range.any? {|n| (3 * n - 2) == index }
  }
```